# Unablet to mount OpenBSD NFS share from MacOS unless I disable firewall

Tags: network, mount, firewall, nfs

I have an OpenBSD server with NFS shares that I can use without any problem from a Linux client. On MacOS, I had to specify the following options `-o nolocks,resvport,vers=3` to get the mount command to work, but even so, the command only succeeds if I disable the firewall on my server. Why might that be the case -- are there any additional ports that I need to open up for a MacOS NFS client?